# Win10: Time since woke from sleep

Tags: windows-10

I want to know how many hours I have been working tonight.

So at a cmd prompt, I do this:

```
systeminfo|find "Time:"
```

That shows me the boot time.

But I booted my system yesterday morning. The computer was asleep last night, and all day today until a few hrs ago when I woke it from sleep.

So how do I find the time it woke from sleep?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Windows event log can be queried from the command-line.

This command will show the most recent power event:

```
wevtutil qe System /rd:true /f:Text /c:1 /q:"<QueryList><Query Id='0' Path='System'><Select Path='System'>*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power']]]</Select></Query></QueryList>"
```

Sample output:

```
Event[0]:
  Log Name: System
  Source: Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
  Date: 2020-07-30T10:19:27.250
  Event ID: 130
  Task: N/A
  Level: Information
  Opcode: Info
  Keyword: N/A
  User: N/A
  User Name: N/A
  Computer: DESKTOP-ABCDEFG
  Description:
Firmware S3 times. SuspendStart: 766335719, SuspendEnd: 766335719
```

The **Date** field gives the local time of the event, which will be the time of the last power event.

```
  Date: 2020-07-30T10:19:27.250
```

This means the PC resumed from sleep at 10:19:27 local time on July 30, 2020.

**wevtutil** is documented here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wevtutil

The `/rd:true` flag specifies to return the most recent events.

The `/c` flag specifies to return only one event. More events can be returned from the log easily. For instance, to see the three most recent power events, change `/c:1` to `/c:3`. This can be useful to see the time the system went to sleep, for example.

The `/q` query expression is an XPath query. It can be derived from the Windows Event Viewer application by clicking on the XML tab:

[image: XML generated for this answer by Windows Event Viewer]

Note that in my example, I changed the double quotes to single quotes to avoid problems with the CMD shell.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! It works!  Two things: a) It would be awesome of the utility could return just the date/time and not all the other stuff; and b) This only works IF you do not change the POWER SOURCE. For example, I woke my laptop from sleep to battery 45 minutes ago. But then I plugged it in 5 min ago. This command now returns the time of 5 minutes ago. EXCELLENT WRITE UP THANK YOU!

Comment: You can use findstr to filter to just the date, and you can change the /c parameter to search for more entries.

I could not find a concise way to filter just the power on event as there are many different kernel messages that can be emitted in my testing. So I suggest combining these techniques like this:

wevtutil qe System /rd:true /f:Text /c:5 /q:"<QueryList><Query Id='0' Path='System'><Select Path='System'>*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power']]]</Select></Query></QueryList>" | findstr /R "Date: ^[a-z]+"

This prints each event, the date/time, and the description.

Comment: On Windows 10 21H1 I had to change the event to `Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter` which gave me the event that shows the sleep and the wake up time. The above only shows when the system went to sleep.

Comment: Be aware the reported time could possibly include 'Z' suffix (zulu aka UTC+0)... but in my case the time was given as local and 'Z' was specified, so it was technically incorrect!! Simply truncate or ignore the 'Z'. Win 10 Enterprise 21H2

Comment: excellent! thanks! how to get only the date of the events without using findstr?

Answer (score 4):

Using PowerShell:

```
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashTable @{ProviderName='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter';LogName='System';ID='1'}
```

will output something like:

```
   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
2023/01/26 09:07:14              1 Information      The system has returned from a low power state....
```

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I find the time it woke from sleep?

You need to look in the system event log, using [Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7).

Look for:

```
Event ID: 1 
Source: Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter
```

To do this:

> 1. If you are using Windows 7, click on the start menu button, enter cmd, right-click cmd.exe and select Run as Administrator.
> 2. If you are using Windows 8.x, use Windows-X to display a command menu, and select Command Prompt (Admin) from the available list.
> 3. Type `eventvwr.msc` to launch the Windows Event Viewer.
> 4. Select Windows Logs > System from the menu in the sidebar.
> 5. Once the log is displayed, select Filter Current Log from the Actions menu.
> 6. A new window opens up that you use to customize what is displayed in the selected event log.
> 7. Locate Event sources there and select Power-Troubleshooter from the context menu. The list is sorted alphabetically, and you should not
>      have any issues finding the filter item in the menu.
> 8. All entries are listed by level, date and time, and Event ID.
> 9. Open the entries closed in date and time to the waking of the PC and check for the Wake Source listing there. It may reveal what woke
>      the computer.

Source [How to find out why your PC wakes up, and how to stop it - gHacks Tech News](https://www.ghacks.net/2013/12/31/find-pc-wakes-stop/)

Example output:

[image]

[image]